# Manhwa where a woman dies and wakes up in the past, then acts strong to prevent being killed again

Tags: story-identification, manga

This girl would purposely dress ugly so that this guy would not like her but she is a beauty. She one day woke up in the past after getting killed, this time she decided to act strong to avoid getting killed. The main lead was this super rich 9th master that was the Boss and he was very possessive. Such as not letting her go to school, until she proved her loyalty etc. He was afraid she would cheat on him.

Once she woke up reborn from the past she realized he loves her. He also had a disease and bad insomnia but only in her presence did he sleep well. The lastest chapter I remember was when she helped prevent him from getting bad injuries by using information in the future. They were going to get attacked but she dresses up as a well known assassin group that had rose bracelet as proof.

Comment: I guess "manwha" = "manga"?

Comment: @gedgar Korean version, I think.

Comment: I highly doubt this is manhua not manga. Just from the vipe of the story is give me.

Answer (score 1):

It should be this one: ***[Perfect Secret Love: The Bad New Wife Is A Little Sweet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/perfect-secret-love-the-bad-new-wife-is-a-little-sweet)***.

> “How perverted is Si Ye Han's taste? He still wants me like this?” Waking up, she looked at her reflection in the mirror: explosive wig, tattoos, and demon-like makeup. Any normal person’s eyes would burn if they looked at her for more than a second. Before her rebirth, she was in love with a different guy, so all she wanted to do was escape from Si Ye Han and hated him to his core after being locked up by him. After her rebirth, she looked differently at him, thinking that maybe he changed for the better?

The FL was always making herself ugly to make her husband hate her, cause she liked another guy. The ML got insomnia. Later she disguises herself as this rose character as you can see in the picture below.

It seems like *Sweet Wife and Romance Revenge* is another name for it btw.

[image]

Comment: When you post a story ID answer, please copy and paste a synopsis into the answer itself, rather than just posting a link to another page with one. Also, if you wish to upload any images, please upload them to i.stack.imgur.com, rather than just imgur.com. You can upload images to i.stack.imgur.com by clicking on the `Image` button while creating a post; it's one of the buttons directly above the box you type your text into.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s called "Sweet Wife and Romance Revenge".

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain how this matches the details of the question?  For example, you might provide quotes or excerpts.  I see you've posted this answer before, but didn't provide any reason that this would match; you should try to make a better answer this time.